# Skip a Jenkins build stage, but keep it running in the background

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to skip a Jenkins build step without reporting its status back?

```
// Build Stage
stage('build') {
}

// Test Stage
stage('test') {
}

// Run at last
stage('Last stage') {
   // I want to mark entire build as succeed regardless of following code 
   //and do not want it to wait for the following code and pipeline to get completed.
   sh """ 
   """
   parallel 'name': {
      build job: "jobname1", propagate: true, wait: false
   }, 'pipeline2': {
      build job: "jobname2", propagate: true, wait: false
   }
}
```

As you can see in the above code block, I want to execute the last stage code and pipelines, but before it gets completed I want to mark the main build as 'Success' status regardless of this code block.

This last stage currently takes more than 2 hrs, and I want it to get skipped for the notifying status but actually exected in the background.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you set propagate to true, which means the job has to wait to determine status of the build.  If you set propagate to false and wait to false then the jobs simply run and your pipeline completes successfully.  Also given that I don't think there is much benefit to executing the builds in parallel.

Comment: That step is working fine, I want to call a shell script before those two builds and I don't want to wait for that shell script to be executed completely...suppose shell script will take 1-2 hours...but instantly as soon as build reaches to 'Last stage' stage, I want to mark it as success and run that stage in background...

Comment: In short, looking for a mechanism to set 'wait:false' stage specific instead of a build.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.  You could put the shell step in parallel with the two external builds, or make the shell step it's own build and run it with the builds step.  In the later case, the 'Last Stage' will complete as soon as the builds are queued - pretty close to what you are looking for.